# Small bug with jQuery on resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm having a strange issue where jQuery does not react as it should.

I'm working on this page : [maelmayon.fr/teddy.php](http://maelmayon.fr/teddy.php)

I'm resizing the article with jQuery so it do the same height as my aside who's more little.

### **jQuery** :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(resizefunction);
        $(window).on('resize', resizefunction);

        function resizefunction() {
          var aside = $('aside').outerHeight();
          $('article').css("height", aside);
        }
    </script>
```

But actually most of the time I finish with a little gap between the content; where this can come from?

You can see on this screen in peach just under the red content.
[image]

If you guys know what's going on, I'll be glad to know!

Comment: Try something like this $('article').css({height:aside+'px'});

Comment: do you have css rule set for your aside such as aside{height:100px}

Comment: The first solution didnt change anything.
And nop I dont have fix any height on my css.

Comment: The "peach gap" can be under the aside content too.

Comment: are you able to acess the value such as var aside = $('aside').outerHeight(); alert(aside);

Comment: It says me 944 what should i understand ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76839/discussion-between-shapcyber-and-baldrani).

Comment: Doesn't it come from borders size? There is a top and bottom borders on the left and one more border on the right which could create the gap.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in your `aside`. It loads content of social networks dinamically, and them change its height. However there should not be problems since you call resize function even on `$(window).load()`, but honestly I don't know why it doesn't work properly in this case.

After some tests only twitter widget seems to cause the problem. To solve you have to call resize function even when the twitter widget is rendered

```
<script src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>twttr.events.bind('rendered',resizefunction);</script>
```

Remember to remove `async` attribute from widget.js script or it will not works as expected.

Reference: https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript/events

Comment: Ok it's indeed due to twitter.

Comment: Has anyone an idea of how to manage to get twitter working well with jQuery ?

Comment: What do you mean with "working well"? As I wrote you just need to recall resize when widget is rendered with `twttr.events.bind('rendered',resizefunction);` into another `<script>` added just after widget.js